# How to loop over a four 4x4 grids?

Tags: algorithm, loops

This is an algorithm question.  I am to write 2 functions.  1 function checks if a 4x4 grid has all integers from 1 to 4 and the other function runs that function for every 4 grid.

This is the pseudocode for the function that takes a single 4x4 grid and adds each of the 4 element into a queue/array/list:

```
function GRIDRUNNER (puzzle, a, b):
       new Queue q
       q.enqueue [puzzle[a][a]]
       q.enqueue [puzzle[a][b]]
       q.enqueue [puzzle[b][a]]
       q.enqueue [puzzle[b][b]]
    return q
end of function
```

Now I want to build a function that applies values for the parameters `a` and `b`.  My question is that how do I build a for-loop system that takes each of the 4 grids, converts them into queues through `GRIDRUNNER`?  The table below gives a visual idea of how the index looks for the entirety of the puzzle. I have to loop through a 2-dimensional array.

```
    0    1  |  2    3

0   _    _  |  _    _

1   _    _  |  _    _

______________________

2   _    _  |  _    _

3   _    _  |  _    _
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
kernel = [(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
list = []

for x,y in kernel
    append(list, GRIDRUNNER(puzzle, 0 + x, 0 + y)

function GRIDRUNNER (puzzle, a, b):
       new Queue q
       q.enqueue [puzzle[a][b]]
       q.enqueue [puzzle[a][b + 1]]
       q.enqueue [puzzle[a + 1][b]]
       q.enqueue [puzzle[a + 1][b + 1]]
    return q
end of function
```

`kernel` is used here to jump over the four grids. The `append` function simply add an element to the end of the list, where elements here are the return values of  the `GRIDRUNNER` function.

*note*: I slightly modified the indices inside `GRIDRUNNER` function.

Comment: Can you explain how `kernel` jumps over the 4 grids?  The values don't make much sense.

Comment: it do that by making a horizontal and vertical offsets for each grid (assuming 0,0 is the starting point).